# Unable to retrive metadata....error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Im still new to MVC and trying to follow a few tutorials (although slightly adapting them to meet my needs).

Im following the Music Store tutorial, and getting an error when trying to create a new controller in step 5 http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-5

When i try to add the controller, i get an error that says 'Unable to retrieve metadata for "myproject.models.form'. Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext' to type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext'.

Any have any ideas how i can fix this?

Comment: Show the code so we can help you better.

Comment: which code? the entire project? Im not exactly sure whats causing the problem, although ive been lead to belive that it could be something do with my connection string `<add name="EPEntities" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EmployeeProcessingV2.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: Can anybody help with this?